# How to attach ethereum mainnet using geth attach?

Tags: go-ethereum

Can I connect to ethereum mainnet by using geth attach without Infura ?
Is there ethereum node publiced in internet?
If answer is no,any suggestion is welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can install GETH ethereum node in your machine and run the geth sync command without specifying testnet. it will automatically sync mainnet data and provide you the RPC URL and you'll connect and use them with web3 providers.

Sync Mode are:

- Full
- Snap
- Light

Answer (score 1):

If your question is if there are any other node providers then yes:

- [Alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com/)
- [Quicknode](https://www.quicknode.com/)
- [And more](https://github.com/arddluma/awesome-list-rpc-nodes-providers#ethereum)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks!
I have tested it successful! The command is ：

geth --datadir "d:\Project\lightnode" --syncmode "light"  --allow-insecure-unlock --http --http.addr 0.0.0.0 console

Then I can deploy my smartcontract and run the function in smartcontract.

Notice：
--allow-insecure-unlock：  You can deploy smartcontract in http.